yolov5 can't find images for training
!cd yolov5 && python train.py --img 320 --batch 16 --epochs 1500 --data dataset.yml --weights yolov5s.pt --workers 2

This is for training the yolov5 model to recognize the labels awake and drowsy via image detection but it cannot detect any image files in the data/images folder. This is for vscode python notebook. The dataset.yml file is as follows:

path: ../data
train: images
val: images
#Classes
nc: 17
names: ['dog',
'person',
'cat',
'tv',
'car',
'meatballs',
'marinara sauce',
'tomato soup',
'chicken noodle soup',
'french onion soup',
'chicken breast',
'ribs',
'pulled pork',
'hamburger',
'cavity',
'awake',
'drowsy'
]
debug: True
debug_verbose: True

I am expecting the model to be properly trained and in the folder ...\Drowsiness Detection using YOLO v5\Project\yolov5\runs\train there are exp folders with best.pt and last.pt in weights folder
